# linked list java refernce

Tags: java, linked-list, insert, implementation

I got a linked list java implementation.But one part i dont understand.my class is

```
class Node {
    int data;
    Node next;
    Node(int d) {
        data = d;
        next = null;
    }
}
```

and i have a fn to insert

```
public static  Node insert(Node head,int data) {
  Node current = head;

  if(head!=null){
    while(current.next!=null){
      current = current.next;  
    }

    current.next = new Node(data);

    return head;
  } else {
    return head=new Node(data);
  }
}
```

the thing i dont understand is ,first we set the head to  a current variable.
and passing next node to the current object for traversal.

My question how it works, since current has ref of head, so when you assign another value technically you are changing head. i could see that with int data.if i update current.data to 0 then i see head is get affected..

may be it is a below par question but please help me to understand whats happening here...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically this function is adding new element as a HEAD element of the linked list collection. Every element has a reference to a NEXT element, so it traverses as long as next element does not exist and then it sets it to the new element (having the data that you passed to the function).
I'm not sure if I understand your concerns, but by changing "current" variable, you are simply changing the "reference" to an object, not changing objects themselves. So you just change the reference as long as the next item does not exist and then you create a new object and set is as referenced by former head (and this object becomes a new head)

Answer (score 0):

I rearranged the code, to make it easier to understand, and added comments :

```
/**
 *Insert a leaf node in a linked list
 *@param head represents the head node of the list.
 *@return the head node 
 */
public static  Node insert(Node head,int data) {

     //if head does not exist, create it and return it 
    if (head==null) {
        return head=new Node(data);
    }

    else{//head exist

        //search for the end of the linked list (leaf, has no next node)
        Node current = head;
        while(current.next!=null){
            current = current.next;  
        }
        //at the end of loop the current.next == null (leaf)
        //add new node as leaf
        current.next = new Node(data);
        return head; //return head unchanged 
    } 

}
```

I hope it help to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

When you are assigning a certain node (not just value) to the current node, you are NOT changing that certain node. Here, you have assigned head to be the current node. But that does not mean both nodes are now the same. They are still different. The `head` node will always have the same value UNTIL someone specifically types `head = [enter another node here]`, assigning a different node **to** the head node. In Java, `=` means assignment and `==` means equals. So assignment and equals are two different concepts.

**Example Singly Linked List:** 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> NULL
(we know `head = Node(1)`)
Now, suppose user calls `insert(head, 4)`?

Execution steps:

1. `Node current = head`, so current == Node(1) and head == Node(1) (current and head are two different nodes, but with same values for now)
2. `head` is null, so execute statements in if statement
3. `current.next == Node(2)` so it's not null. Execute statement in while loop
4. `current = current.next` so current is assigned Node(2)
5. `current.next == Node(3)` so it's not null. Execute statement in while loop
6. `current = current.next` so current is assigned Node(3)
7. `current.next == NULL`, so stop while loop
8. `current.next = new Node(4)`, so we assigned Node(4) to current.next
9. Now we return list starting at head. And head = Node(1) still.

Result : 1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> NULL